Why I can't access directly properties in kotlin
I tried to call default methods in kotlin but it's give me an error liuke unsolved reference error.
I did tried on this way but this code returned me an error.

Unresolved reference 'length'.

fun main(){
    val box= Box()
    box.x=100

}
class Box{
    var x:Int?=null
        set(value) {
            if(value.length>1){
                println(value)
            }else{
                println("it can not be empty")
            }
        }
}

and i tried this one. but it's work fine. the question is why this one required "toString()" method

fun main(){
    val box= Box()
    box.x=100

}
class Box{
    var x:Int?=null
        set(value) {
            if(value.toString().length>1){
                println(value)
            }else{
                println("it can not be empty")
            }
        }
}


value is a nullable Int. An Int doesn’t have any length property. There is no such thing as the length of a number (in programming terms).
Even if it did have the property you want, it could have a value of null, so you would first have to add a check for it not being null before trying to use that property.
When you call toString() on an Int, it converts it to a String, and a String does have a length, the number of characters it contains.
This works even though the Int might be null, because a null value can be converted using toString() to the literal String "null". The else branch of your code will never happen because there is no possible value of an Int? that would be converted to an empty (zero-length) String.

Also, you generally should avoid using nullable variables and properties unless you really need to be able to represent a null value. Nulls make code more complicated. In Kotlin, they make it more difficult to work with properties because you keep having to check for the possibility that it is null. In languages that don’t have null safety, you generally avoid nullability (in an unconstrained-by-the-compiler way) where you can because they are a frequent source of runtime crashes.
